# Water-damaged Macbook Pro - everything except keyboard and trackpad works

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, hardware, trackpad, repair

A family member gave me a 13" mid-2015 Macbook Pro that had been water-damaged. Besides the battery being dead, the computer booted up fine. The only two things that don't work are the keyboard and trackpad. However, the keyboard backlighting and power button do work. Running Apple Diagnostics (using an external keyboard), I found a hardware error code PPN001. Apple has quoted this repair at about $900 USD, so I'm trying to see if I can do a repair myself for less.

**Would it be possible for me to do the hardware repairs myself (ie: is the logic board still ok), and if so, what parts need replacement?**

*Note that I have the skill to do the hardware repairs, I'm just unsure of what repairs are needed. (I miss having GSX access.)

Comment: You need something called a Top Case assembly which includes the battery, trackpad and keyboard.  You’ll have to disassemble the entire machine to do this repair

Comment: [This page at iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Search?query=13%22+mid-2015+Macbook+Pro) has pertinent information and parts.

Comment: Take the whole thing apart and check if there are any liquids or residues thereof left on parts that might cause shorts. Clean everything carefully with a clean and soft toothbrush and 100% isopropyl alcohol (cheaply available from eBay), especially connectors of the trackpad and keyboard (you can just submerge the whole logic board into the IPA, just make sure to let it dry, maybe in an oven at low temperatures). The trackpad can be replaced relatively easily, the keyboard not so much.